# BIM 360 Unable to create version of existing file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am following the instructions from [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) to version a file.

I am calling this endpoint: "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.f67f2d2a-13e0-4764-9cc4-3cbb3ce4ecf8/versions"

This is the json that I'm sending:

```
    "jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},
"data":{
    "attributes":{
        "extension":{
            "type":"versions:autodesk.core:File",
            "version":"1.0"
            },
        "name":"saw.txt"
    },
    "relationships":{
        "item":{
            "data":{
                "type":"items",
                "id":"urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:LvhVsjRMRSeilxRYaO8Blw"
                }
            },
        "storage":{
            "data":{
                "type":"objects",
                "id":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/fb277d09-7049-4474-8762-e9a5723e1e48.txt"
                }
            }
        },
    "type":"versions"
}
```

And the response that I'm receiving:

```
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"7df0a3d5-376a-4607-ae7a-6726772785c4","status":"400","code":"BAD_INPUT","title":"One or more input values in the request were bad","detail":"Request input is invalid for this operation."}]}"
```

I know that the project and file Ids are valid, and that creating the bucket and uploading the file have succeeded. What else can I do to determine why the versioning is failing?

Answer (score 0):

The project id contains **'b.'**, which  means you are working with BIM 360 file. The type should be **versions:autodesk.bim360:File**, instead of **versions:autodesk.core:File**(which is for files in other types of hub such as Autodesk 360).

A demo payload when creating a version for BIM 360 file

```
 {
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "versions",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "advanced.rvt",
      "extension": {
        "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
        "version": "1.0"
      }
    },
    "relationships": {
      "items": {
        "data": {
          "type": "items",
          "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:recSpZViRvmXWzVU7TKcMw"
        }
      },
      "storage": {
          "data": {
            "type": "objects",
            "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/05138bae-977b-4401-9846-
```

958968ca19ec.rvt"
              }
            }
        }
      }

```
}
```

Similarly, when you create a new item (first version), the payload would be like:

```
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "items",
    "attributes": {
      "displayName": "advanced.rvt",
      "extension": {
        "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
        "version": "1.0"
      }
    },
    "relationships": {
      "tip": {
        "data": {
          "type": "versions",
          "id": "1"
        }
      },
      "parent": {
        "data": {
          "type": "folders",
          "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.oWrOwMCWTpWH-_glicursA"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "versions",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "advanced-mott.rvt",
        "extension": {
          "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
          "version": "1.0"
        }
      },
      "relationships": {
        "storage": {
          "data": {
            "type": "objects",
            "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/caa01ab2-c1da-4e51-8ae6- 
    892179a12b62.rvt"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. If you have not already, please consider updating the documentation page in the tutorial and for the API endpoint to point this out.

Comment: thank you for the comments, I will forward to document team.